# C++ ifstream on XCode: Where is the default directory?

Tags: c++, ifstream

Ok, so this is the first time I've coded C++ in Xcode (I'm used to ObjC)and I've now started a programming course at my college.

I'm trying to open a file (either hard coded or from user input in the console) and no matter what I try, it says the file won't open (through error checking)

I'm assuming it's because the test.txt file I have isn't in the assumed root directory, so if that's the case, what is the root directory?

Here's my code so far:

```
//include files
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Global Variables
short inputPicture[512][512];
short outputPicture[512][512];

//Function Prototypes
void getInput(char* in, char* out);
void initializeArray(ifstream* input);

//Main
int main(){
    //local variables
    char inputFile[32];
    char outputFile[32];

    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;


    getInput(inputFile, outputFile);
    cout << inputFile << endl;//test what was sent back from the function

    input.open(inputFile, ifstream::in);
    if (!input.is_open()){//check to see if the file exists
        cout << "File not found!\n";
        return 1;//if not found, end program
    }

    initializeArray(&input);

    return 0;
}//end Main

//Gets initial input from user
void getInput(char* in, char* out){
    cout << "Please designate input file: ";
    cin >> in;
    cout << "\nPlease designate an output file: ";
    cin >> out;
}//end getInput


//Sets the global array to the information on the input file
void initializeArray(ifstream* input){



}//end initializeArray
```

Please let me know if there's something else wrong I'm doing, as I'm sure that's always a great possibility :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default directory should be relative the application's working directory, which is usually the same place the application is located (debuggers can mess with that, sometimes).

For simple testing, just specify an absolute path in the command line (or code).

To get the current directory (to see), the `getcwd()` C function (also usable in C++) will help. Something like:

```
char * dir = getcwd(NULL, 0); // Platform-dependent, see reference link below    
printf("Current dir: %s", dir);
```

That should display it in the console. The `getcwd` function has a few variations depending on what you run on, I've not tested on Mac, but info here:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd

Comment: What header do I need to include to get access to the getcwd()?

Comment: Ok, it worked with that. Thanks. So, when I turn this program in, I just need to make sure the test.txt and output file I'm using are with the .exe if my professor is using a PC to run the program? (silly question, I know, but just making sure.)

Comment: You shouldn't need the output file, that should be created, and I would recommend changing any absolute paths to relative before you hand it in. Once you've diagnosed where it's trying to load from and know what to expect, just put the input file in the right place and/or include instructions.

Answer (score 5):

In the Xcode *(v7.1.1 at the time of writing)* sidebar, there's an automatically generated folder called "Products". Inside you'll find the executable of your project (assuming you've built your project at least once). Right-click it & choose "Show in Finder". A folder will open in Finder. That's the working directory of your program, & you'll notice it's not actually inside your project's folder.

You can have Xcode use a different directory instead. In the top toolbar, on the left side where it shows your project name next to the active build architecture, click on the Project name > Edit Scheme…

Then look for an option called "Working Directory" in the sheet that appears. Tick the checkbox & then choose a custom directory. ***Note***: Make sure the "Run" option is the selected one in that sheet's sidebar.

Comment: I can confirm this is still valid for xcode 12 :)

Answer (score 3):

The "root" directory that your executable is looking for the file in is not the actual `/` root directory of the file-system, but is the directory that the executable is executing in ... if you are using Xcode, this may be buried inside one of the build directories automatically created by Xcode for your project rather than a user home folder or home folder sub-directory like `/Users/XXXXXX/Documents`.

Comment: Ok, I went as far as I can go into the directory, and it still won't find the file... What does an executable look like on a mac? lol Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: An executable doesn't have an extension on the Mac (or in Unix), although sometimes it has a .app extension which is actually a package (i.e., it's a special folder structure).  If Xcode has created a .app for your file, then right-click on it and choose `view package contents`.  Inside there will be a `MacOSX` directory, and inside that directory there will be a `bin` directory.  Your executable should be inside of there.  Otherwise, if this is a simple command-line app, then Xcode should have a default build directory it uses to create your compiled binaries in.

Answer (score 2):

The "default directory" is the directory from which the executable was executed. Usually this is in the same folder as the executable, although if you do stuff like dragging and dropping files on an exe, it can change the startup path.

The path can also change if you're running the program from inside your IDE. The IDE starts the executable, so there's no telling where it's doing it from. You'll have to find where it stores executables and put the file in there, or use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
 - getcwd(NULL, 0) returned "/".
 - and couldn't use abusolute path.(It changes on each terminal deployed.)

So I got the path by ObjC code and throw it to c++ function.

1.Put files in top directory of xcode project. And check they are included in "Targets"->"Build Phases"->"Copy Bundle Resources".

2.Get the path by ObjC code.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* resourceDirectoryPath = [bundle bundlePath];
NSString* path = [resourceDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString: @"/"];
```

3.And throw it to c++ function.

```
[self cppFunc:[path UTF8String]];
```

4.Then you can make an ablsolute file path in c++.

```
std::string file = path(arg) + "filename";
```

It worked for me.